# Mysql script to Replicate all rows into same table and other table too

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- `task_manager`
- `key_result_area`

In `task_manager` I have some data those year_code is `NULL` and I have to duplicate all the rows with the update `year_code="2017-2018"`.

And at the same time, I have to add all the replicated data into `key_result_area` table with the foreign key `task_manager_id`. I am facing difficulty to make script for that.

I was trying this but it's not working.

```
INSERT INTO task_manager 
(employee_id, year_code,task_name, kra_flag, 
created_by,date_of_creation,date_of_modification,modified_by) 

SELECT employee_id, "2017-2018",task_name, kra_flag, 
    created_by,date_of_creation,date_of_modification,modified_by 
FROM task_manager WHERE year_code = null
```

sample data: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question.  Can you add some sample data and table structure to your question?

Comment: NULL and '' are not the same thing in MySQL

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added the screenshot of table can you please check.

Comment: @Strawberry I have changes '' to null but that is also not giving result

Comment: you want to duplicate the records instead of updating the record with the missing data?

Comment: Use `WHERE year_code IS NULL`

Comment: @LelioFaieta first i want duplicate all the row in table task_manager from same table task_manager table and those duplicate record should have auto incremented id and year_code="2017-2018" then Second I have to update key_result_area table that has task_manager_id

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks task_manager updation is working. Now At the same time I have to update key_result_area table that has task_manager_id. How can i add the sql in the same existing sql

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but you probably will need two queries here.  An insert adds new records and an update modifies existing records.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. In the task_manager table I have to duplicate all the rows so adding new record in the task_manager table. And same time those new record also should go to key_result_area table and key_result_area table has task_manager foreign key. Is that clear now??

Comment: Thanks all got the script